# How to run windows exe (dos commands) from my client (using Jquery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, command-line

I want to have few links on my page, which would in turn call window's "Control Panel", "DeviceManager", "InstalledPrograms" etc.

I have found out the equivalent Commands for running these exes, Please help me with the ways to call them from my Jquery code.

(FYI) The commands for
1. Control Panel is : control.exe
2. DeviceManager is : %SystemRoot%\System32\devmgmt.msc
3. InstalledPrograms is : control.exe appwiz.cpl

Comment: You wanna run executables on the client computer from jQuery? Are you hearing yourself?

Comment: Some SO questions frighten me.

Comment: @PeteWilson - I still remember the guy asking how to protect his database from the DBA.

Comment: :) I know its should not be allowed, but think a scenario if we are scanning the system for Software / hardware problems & want to provide the solution in terms of links (say derangement your system)

Comment: @Biki, if you are scanning for hardware problems you are not writing a website to do so. You write a native desktop application that you give to your client so that he runs it and so on. On your web site of course you could provide a link to the .zip file containing this application so that the client can download it and of course if he trusts you run it on his own machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run executables through the browser, not without some sort of plug-in installed.

This is for reasons both of security and privacy.

Just imagine for a moment what things would look like if any random website could execute any program on your machine.

Comment: True, It should be restricted for the client to perform any such operations. Still can I achieve this with a confirmation from the user? May be by using admin privilege or under any secure account?

Comment: @Biki - As I said, not without a browser plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with others that its a bad idea I can think of a legitimate reason you would want to do this. e.g. a technical troubleshooting guide for your company Intranet and its employees, clickable hyperlinks to open said programs would be useful and easier then getting the reader to type them in via command prompt. How about a simple hyper link?

- If you want to do this across the internet, forget it, it's a big no no.
- If you want to do it internally for Intranet users, just add the servers URL to trusted zones in IE and it should work
- If your doing this locally then it will work fine with the `file://` URI

[image]

```
<a href="file://c:\windows\System32\appwiz.cpl">Open Installed Programs</a>
```

Comment: I ve tried using it locally in my computer, but it has not worked, as shown above. Have you done any additional settings in ur browser?

Comment: Locally it works fine for me in Chrome and IE9 on default settings. I haven't tried FireFox, what are you using?

Comment: I am also using IE9 & chrome. Even I ve tested the same code in two of my colleagues machine, but the prompt is not coming to choose either to open / save / cancel.